# How to bind a network namespace to a interface device through a macvlan

Tags: networking

I am trying to connect a new network namespace to a netwrok device with the following commands:

```
# create macvlan and associate it to network device in bride mode
ip link add macvlan1 link dev1 type macvlan mode bridge

# create new netwrok namespace
ip netns add net1

# associate the macvlan to the nbew namespace
ip link set macvlan1 netns net1

# set macvlan to up
ip netns exec net1 ifconfig macvlan1 up
```

When I try to ping from new namespace, error "connect: Network is unreachable" is returned.

---

Edit:

```
ip addr show dev1:
4: dev1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 68:05:ca:8e:82:d8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.65.107/24 brd 192.168.65.255 scope global dynamic dev1
   valid_lft 490223sec preferred_lft 490223sec
inet6 fe80::d257:2f1:9c21:3a13/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

ip route:
default via 192.168.65.1 dev dev1  proto static  metric 100 
default via 25.25.40.1 dev ethernet0  metric 1000 
25.25.40.0/24 dev ethernet0  proto kernel  scope link  src 25.25.40.143 
169.254.0.0/16 dev dev1  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.1.4 via 192.168.65.1 dev dev1  proto dhcp  metric 100 
192.168.65.0/24 dev dev1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.65.107  metric 100
```

Comment: Try giving `macvlan1` an IP address and proper routes. Verify with `ip addr` and `ip route`. (This is easier if you start an `xterm` in the new namespace).

Comment: How can I assign an address to the macvlan? There isn't any sample code for that online.

Comment: The same way you assign it to a physical network interface. For example manually, with `ip addr add ...` in the namespace (or `ip netns exec net1 ip addr add ...`, or `ip -n net1 addr add ...` outside of it), preferably with a valid IP address in the subnet. Please edit your question with the output of `ip addr show dev1` (assuming `dev1` is the correct name) and `ip route` if you don't know what to do.

Comment: @dirkt I edited the question with routing table states. When I try to add an address with "ip netns exec net1 ip addr add 192.168.65.100" an error states that a "dev" argument is required. When I try "ip netns exec net1 ip addr add 192.168.65.100/24 dev enp45s0", an error "cannot find device" is returned.

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend launching a `xterm` in the network namespace with `ip netns exec ...`, it saves a lot of typing.

As you can see with `ip -n net1 link list`, the network interfaces in the namespace are `macvlan1` (and `lo`). So would you need to do is

```
ip -n net1 addr add 192.168.65.100/24 dev macvlan1
```

(before you do a `link set macvlan1 up` on it). Note that this *should* automatically add routes to `192.168.65.100/24` on `macvlan1` in the network namespace, but verify this with

```
ip -n net1 route
```

Now you should be able to ping it (as your type is "bridge") from the main network namespace:

```
ping 192.168.65.100
```

In the same way, you should be able to ping the main network namespace interface from the new namespace:

```
ip netns exec net1 ping 192.168.65.107
```

All this assumes the address `192.168.65.100` isn't used by some other device in the network, otherwise funny things may happen.

Comment: It's not working. When I try: ping 192.168.65.100, from the main namspace, it returns "Host Unreacheable". Ip route of the namespace is: 192.168.65.0/24 dev macvlan1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.65.100.